# Delay when creating S3 bucket and accessing it from ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've created a bucket using cloud formation, 
with some name (let's say `test-bucket`) and `AccessControl='Private'`

then I added a policy to my ec2 like these:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
    ]
}
```

now I try to reach it from my ec2 using this command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket
```

and I get this error:

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: No AWSAccessKey was presented.
```

Now I've read in here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=801522 that there's some propagation delay until the ec2 can discover the bucket but it's been over an hour. any thoughts what's wrong or how much time I need to wait?

**I don't want to make the bucket accessible publicly. Only from this specific ec2**

---

**After about two hours it started working, without any change.
Is there any workaround to decrease this time?**

Comment: you need to add a `bucket policy` to allow access from a particular EC2 only.

Comment: You are not properly authenticated, this is why the operation failed. How do you provide your AWS access and secret keys?

Comment: `No AWSAccessKey was presented` certainly seems like incorrect behavior on the part of aws-cli.  That should never happen, so verify that you are using the latest version.  It would be potentially informative to capture the output with `--debug` but there would be a large amount of information to sort through.  The overall problem seems like a synchronization issue with your instance role.  In search of a workaround, stopping and restarting the instance (not just a reboot, it needs to be a full stop/start) might be a worthwhile test.

Comment: I understand your answers, but why it started working after two hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's an issue with the version of awscli, updating it solves the issue